# How can I tell selenium to start firefox with certain commandline options?

Tags: firefox, selenium, command-line

I'm using a custom firefox binary with selenium that is dependant on specific commandline parameters.

How can I tell selenium to use these parameters when executing the firefox binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oops, it seems there is a method: FirefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions()

That's probably the answer...