# Open firefox devtools programmatically with FirefoxProfile

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, firebug

How can I launch Firefox 52 with opened devtools using selenium and Java?

Before the merge of Firebug into the Firefox DevTools I used FirefoxProfile to open the console programmatically:

```
profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.console.enableSites", true);
```

etc.

But Firebug does not work anymore now. 
So what is the proper way to launch with opened network or console tab?

And also, is there any analog extension to FirePath to launch automatically and use instead of the currently broken FirePath extension?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to launch Firefox with given page and native devtools open from command line using **`-devtools` parameter**:

```
firefox -no-remote -profile "c:\deleteme" -devtools -url "http://example.com/"
```

It seems to be possible to pass that parameter to the WebDriver by calling 
[`addCommandLineOptions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html#addCommandLineOptions-java.lang.String...-)`("-devtools")` on the `FirefoxBinary` instance.

(Via [How can I tell selenium to start firefox with certain commandline options?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256650/540955).)

---

Or in Node perhaps by `firefox.Options().setBinary(…).`[`addArguments`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js#L246-L254)`("-devtools")`

Spotted the parameter in `firefox -help | more`, but alas, seems that not all information presented there as well as info given at [Command_Line_Options MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#Other_Components) are still valid. The `-devtools` one is missing at the MDN page at this moment.